# QFT butterfly structure

Tags: quantum-fourier-transform

Any idea why QFT does not require butterfly structure ?

or probably it is already implied in https://medium.com/a-bit-of-qubit/quantum-fourier-transform-qubits-and-discrete-fourier-transform-5871c4cba9ff

Note: I am comparing QFT against [conventional FFT](https://zipcpu.com/dsp/2018/10/02/fft.html)

[image: 3_bits_qft]

Comment: what do you define as "butterfly structure"?

Comment: @epelaez see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_diagram